# Did Youtube Api undergo a dramatic change last year?

Tags: api, youtube

Since mid 2012 I was using YouTube api from url http://www.youtube.com/player_api

To initialize YouTube objects I used following method:

```
new YT.Player();
```

In mid 2012 when I was building the web app, Youtube api didnt require to register and retrieve any unique api keys.

During 2013 the web app started to fail occasionally (sometimes it would work, sometimes it would fail even without making any changes to the code).

As of 2014 the web app does not work at all.
Chrome debugging feature shows following error when it calls the above **YT** constructor

```
undefined is not a function
```

Did Youtube api undergo changes that disabled open api and only offers private api? I was not able to find any such documentation regarding updates in 2013 / 2014.

Comment: I used it 2 months ago and did not have any problem. Could you show us your `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function? That is where you need to do `new YT.Player();` . Also, in your HTML, don't forget to declare the youtube api javascript AFTER your own script. So that `onYoutubeIframeAPIReady` is already defined when the API triggers it.

Comment: That could actually be the problem. I didnt use onYoutubeIframeAPIReady method and it used to work back a year ago. I cant find old copy of api that I built upon two years ago. There must have been some change to the API because the web app used to work find for months.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I found a very simple fix for my case.

To recap, my issue was that in mid 2012 I built a web app based on YouTube player JS API. At the beginning of 2014 the YouTube player JS API stopped working without any changes to the code.

I discovered I needed to add the following code to each instance of iframe as part of the requested url. Thats all.

```
enablejsapi=1
```